# How do I always get COMException instead of OutOfMemoryException?

Tags: c#, .net, com, exception, com-interop

My C# code consumes a COM object. Sometimes that COM object methods will return `E_OUTOFMEMORY` but it will get translated into `System.OutOfMemoryException` instead of `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException` with appropriate `ErrorCode`. This is a problem for me because it complicates my error handling - I'd prefer to have all error indications that arise from COM object methods being thrown as `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException` only.

Is it possible to always have `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException` and not `System.OutOfMemoryException` when a COM object method returns `E_OUTOFMEMORY`?

Comment: Feature, not a bug, you can't turn that off.  OOM means that the *process* ran out of virtual memory, not the COM server.  And is just as likely to strike on a managed allocation.  Handling OOM is questionable, you can't magically extend the VM size.  It should be done very close to the call site so you can recover program state.  At which point you *know* that the COM server fell over.

Comment: @Hans Passant: Great, except the COM server is outproc and so the invoking process couldn't care less about it's OOM state.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a bit of a cop-out, but why not wrap whatever code is throwing the `System.OutOfMemoryException` in a Try/catch and re-throw a `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException`?

Something along the lines of:

```
    try
        {
            // COM Code here
        }
        catch (System.OutOfMemoryException ex)
        {
            throw new System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException("E_OUTOFMEMORY", ex);
        }
```

Comment: That would require wrapping every call and I have like dozens or maybe even thousands of them.